# How to join element values in XQuery for SQL Server?

Tags: sql-server, xquery

If I have this XML

```
<TradingInquirySearchResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SearchTerm>test</SearchTerm>
  <CompanyFound>true</CompanyFound>
  <CompanyInfoCollection>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyID>26</CompanyID>
      <CompanyName>test</CompanyName>
      <Status>Unrestricted</Status>
      <SearchTags>
        <Tag>test2</Tag>
        <Tag>test3</Tag>
        <Tag>test4</Tag>
      </SearchTags>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </CompanyInfoCollection>
</TradingInquirySearchResult>
```

I want to get `"test2;test3;test4"`. How can I join the values of `<Tag>` for the first `<CompanyInfo>` tag?

I tried `TransactionData.value('(/TradingInquirySearchResult/CompanyInfoCollection/CompanyInfo[1]/SearchTags/Tag)[1]', 'nvarchar(1000)')`

but it didn't work.

Thanks

Comment: What version of SQL Server?

Comment: sql server 2012 (compatibility level 110)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're using SQL Server 2012 (or rather not 2017+) the common way to aggregate strings is to use `FOR XML PATH` and `STUFF`, and you can get the multiple values for the node `Tag` using the `nodes` operator. This gives you the below:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '
<TradingInquirySearchResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SearchTerm>test</SearchTerm>
  <CompanyFound>true</CompanyFound>
  <CompanyInfoCollection>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyID>26</CompanyID>
      <CompanyName>test</CompanyName>
      <Status>Unrestricted</Status>
      <SearchTags>
        <Tag>test2</Tag>
        <Tag>test3</Tag>
        <Tag>test4</Tag>
      </SearchTags>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </CompanyInfoCollection>
</TradingInquirySearchResult>';


SELECT STUFF((SELECT N';' +  ST.Tag.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
              FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
              CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/TradingInquirySearchResult/CompanyInfoCollection/CompanyInfo/SearchTags/Tag') ST(Tag)
              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') AS Tags
```

*Edit for guess when multiple companies.*

If you only want the first company, then yes, using `[1]` would work:

```
DECLARE @XML xml = '
<TradingInquirySearchResult xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <SearchTerm>test</SearchTerm>
  <CompanyFound>true</CompanyFound>
  <CompanyInfoCollection>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyID>26</CompanyID>
      <CompanyName>test</CompanyName>
      <Status>Unrestricted</Status>
      <SearchTags>
        <Tag>test2</Tag>
        <Tag>test3</Tag>
        <Tag>test4</Tag>
      </SearchTags>
    </CompanyInfo>
    <CompanyInfo>
      <CompanyID>27</CompanyID>
      <CompanyName>Sample</CompanyName>
      <Status>Restricted</Status>
      <SearchTags>
        <Tag>test6</Tag>
        <Tag>test7</Tag>
        <Tag>test8</Tag>
      </SearchTags>
    </CompanyInfo>
  </CompanyInfoCollection>
</TradingInquirySearchResult>';


SELECT STUFF((SELECT N';' +  ST.Tag.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
              FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
              CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/TradingInquirySearchResult/CompanyInfoCollection/CompanyInfo[1]/SearchTags/Tag') ST(Tag)
              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') AS Tags;
```

If, however, you want a row per company, then you would want to do something like this:

```
SELECT CIC.CI.value('(./CompanyID/text())[1]','nvarchar(50)') AS CompanyID,
       STUFF((SELECT N';' +  ST.Tag.value('(./text())[1]','nvarchar(100)')
              FROM CIC.CI.nodes('./SearchTags/Tag') ST(Tag)
              FOR XML PATH(N''),TYPE).value('.','nvarchar(MAX)'),1,1,N'') AS Tags
FROM (VALUES(@XML))V(X)
CROSS APPLY V.X.nodes('/TradingInquirySearchResult/CompanyInfoCollection/CompanyInfo') CIC(CI);
```

Comment: This looks insanely complicated to understand lol. Also it should only work for the first `CompanyInfo` tag. If I add another, this code includes the Tags in that too.

Comment: but I think that can be fixed with `CompanyInfo[1]`

Comment: @omega I can only base an answer on the example i have. If you have other scenarios, or the sample data you provide isn't representative of the data you have, then you will get answers that reflect the incomplete data.

Comment: `FOR XML PATH` has been quite a common process for years. It was only recently that it become even simpler, with the introduction of `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: I've added a couple of extra answers based on your latest comment, @omega, but they are guesses, as I don't have any extra sample data or expected results to work with.